# Word for something happening after it is mentioned

Tags: single-word-requests

When something happens when it, or something related to it, was previously mentioned. It doesn't necessarily have to be wished.

It is almost similar to "speaking of the devil".

My friend talked about her high school reunion and I told her that I haven't seen my high school friends since I graduated. The next day, I bumped into my high school friend at a mutual friend's party.

Comment: The term I would use in that situation is `serendipity` or a a happy accident. It doesn't, however, connote that this event was previously alluded to.

Comment: Thank you but I want to use it as a verb. Like ' you jinxed it'

Comment: It is not related to *jinx* -- that word unnecessarily distracts from the context.

Comment: I see. You should edit your post and include an example sentence with a blank for the desired word.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What a good question! It is considered good practice to provide a sentence with a gap when asking single-word-requests. An example might be the sentence "When I poke a jelly and it makes a wavy motion, it is ____.", to which the answer might be "wobble".

Comment: *portended*, *augured*, *foreshadowed*, *foretold*,  *prognosticated*.  In order of my preference / increasing conscious thought.

Comment: Not quite [manifest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manifest): "to make something happen by imagining it and consciously thinking that it will happen". That's generally more deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

[**Synchronicity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity)

> Synchronicity is a concept, first introduced by analytical
>   psychologist [Carl Jung](https://carl-jung.net/synchronicity.html), which holds that events are "meaningful
>   coincidences" if they occur with no causal relationship yet seem to be
>   meaningfully related.

Answer (score 0):

In fiction (and in real life), this is called foreshadowing.

> **foreshadow** *tr.v.*
> To present an indication or a suggestion of beforehand; presage: hostilities that foreshadowed all-out war.
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=foreshadow)

Answer (score -1):

PROPHESY

From 'CollinsCobuild':

If you prophesy that something will happen, you say that you strongly believe that it will happen.

Comment: But no-one in the OP's example expressed a belief, strong or otherwise, that they would run into an old school friend the next day.

Comment: Look at the example sentence you copy/pasted from Collins.  Notice how the word is spelled. Then look at how you spelled it.  Given this is a site intended to provide expertise in English, it's really better if you run any answers you post through a spellchecker before you commit them.

Answer (score -1):

**to tempt fate**

usually meaning

> test in a way  that usually involves risk or danger

and taken from Collins English Dictionary:

> *As soon as you start to talk about never having played on a losing*
>   *side, it is tempting fate.*

**Tempting fate** is speaking of something (negative) happening, then it happens.
Synonyms include *to ask for it, to push one's luck etc.*

This would be a perfect answer to your question, but the only catch is it's negative only.

All definitions taken from Oxford Dictionaries except where stated otherwise.